# Interpretation of glmmPQL() spatial autocorrelation output

Tags: r, mixed-model, interpretation, autocorrelation, random-effects-model

I am modeling binominal data with random effects and spatial autocorrelation using `MASS::glmmPQL()`.
Plotting the residual semivariogram of a model fit **without** accounting for spatial autocorrelation leads me to the following semivariogram:

[image]

Hence, I set up a corSpatial object to account for the spatial autocorrelaton within my data.

```
correl = corSpatial(value = c(1911, 0.03), form = ~ry + rx, 
                    nugget = TRUE,
                    fixed = FALSE, type = "spherical")
```

After inspecting the fit of the model which accounts for spatial autorcorrelation using the `correl` object introduced above, I get the following output when calling `summary()` (note that "date" is a random effect):

```
Correlation Structure: Spherical spatial correlation
 Formula: ~ry + rx | date 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      range      nugget 
329.0934685   0.2516632
```

I visualized the residuals(?) again in a variogram using `nlme::Variogram()`

```
plot(nlme::Variogram(fit5, form = ~rx + ry, data = d, 
     maxDist = 20000, breaks = c(50, 200, 400, 600, 1000, 
                 1500, 2000, seq(2700,29700,by = 1000)), 
               robust = FALSE), smooth = TRUE, span = 0.65, 
               showModel = FALSE)
```

[image]

Leaving me confused.

1. How do I interpret the `summary()` outcome?
2. How to deal with the `nlme::Variogram()` output showing a totally different shape compared to the resid. svgm/summary() output?
3. What did I do wrong?